# How to check if node in scene contains a matching geometryid?

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, scene

I have a function that loops my scene to get a specific node. Once it gets this node, it traverses its children and checks if any of the children have *geometry* or *material* properties. If they do, then I `dispose()` then `remove` the child.

Before I `dispose()` now I want to check if the *geometry.id* of that child matches any other children geometry ids in the scene. If it matches, then I don't `dispose` I just `remove` it. If it doesn't have any matching geometry id, then I can `dispose` then `remove` it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try reference counting?

```
var counts = {};

// when adding mesh
counts[mesh.geometry.id] = (counts[mesh.geometry.id] || 0) + 1;

// when removing mesh
counts[mesh.geometry.id]--;
if (counts[mesh.geometry.id] == 0) {
    // safe to dispose
}
```